# Using Promises In A For Loop.. How Do You Tell When It's Finished?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, fetch, es6-promise

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8ocdupar/

```js
var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
console.log("DONE!!!")
```

In this straightforward example, I have a fetch promise inside a for loop. Based on the length
of the array it will make the fetch call 6 times. My question is, how can I tell when it's done?

I don't understand async behavior very well. To me, it seems I want this example to actually behave
synchronously.

When that loop is done and has made all the calls, I just want to log that it's done.

This is what the example currently outputs:

```
DONE!!!
(index):39 Response {type: "cors", url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", redirected: false, 
status: 200, ok: true, …}
(index):39 Response {type: "cors", url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", redirected: false, 
status: 200, ok: true, …}
(index):39 Response {type: "cors", url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", redirected: false, 
status: 200, ok: true, …}
(index):39 Response {type: "cors", url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", redirected: false, 
status: 200, ok: true, …}
(index):39 Response {type: "cors", url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", redirected: false, 
status: 200, ok: true, …}
(index):39 Response {type: "cors", url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", redirected: false, 
status: 200, ok: true, …}
```

And this is what I want it to output:

```
(index):39 Response {type: "cors", url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", redirected: false, 
status: 200, ok: true, …}
(index):39 Response {type: "cors", url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", redirected: false, 
status: 200, ok: true, …}
(index):39 Response {type: "cors", url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", redirected: false, 
status: 200, ok: true, …}
(index):39 Response {type: "cors", url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", redirected: false, 
status: 200, ok: true, …}
(index):39 Response {type: "cors", url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", redirected: false, 
status: 200, ok: true, …}
(index):39 Response {type: "cors", url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", redirected: false, 
status: 200, ok: true, …}
DONE!!!
```

Comment: you mean something like `Promise.all(arr.map(nr => fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/" + nr))).then(console.log);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `async` and `await`:

```js
(async function () {
  var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
    let o = await response.json(); // <-- you'll want this too...
    console.log(o);
  }
  console.log("DONE!!!")
})(); // <-- execute it
```

Comment: This has the side effect of the requests executing sequentially rather than in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Promise.all` to create a new Promise that resolves once all provided Promises have resolved.

```js
let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let promises = []

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  promises.push(
    window
      .fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
      })
  )
}

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  console.log("DONE!!!")
})
```

Comment: This is the way to do it in general unless one request is dependent on a result of a previous one.  Then the later will need to wait for the former to complete. +1

Answer (score 0):

When you call `fetch`, it will return a Promise object that will resolve when a response is available. JavaScript doesn't *automatically* do anything with this Promise object, though; you have to be explicit about what you want to do with it.

The basic usage for a promise is typically "do something when this promise is resolved", which works by calling the `.then()` method on the Promise object with a callback function passed; you already show that in your code by doing `.then(response => { console.log(response) })`.

In order to know when *multiple* promises have finished, use the static `Promise.all` function. You'll need to keep track of all the Promise objects you create by storing them in an array...

```
const promises = [];
for (/* each item in the array */) {
    promises.push(fetch(...));
}
```

Then pass that array to `Promise.all`. This will actually return a new Promise object -- this one will resolve when *all* the passed promises are done:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
    ...
});
```

What's that `data` variable? It will be an array of all the values resolved by each promise in the `promises` array. So, in this example, it will be every Response object.

(An important PS: When you do `promise.then(cb)`, it will return a new promise; this new promise will resolve when the `cb` function resolves, and its resolved value will be whatever `cb` returned. This is extra useful to know when you're using `Promise.all`, in case for example you want to get the *body* of the response; you'd do `promises.push(fetch(...).then(res => res.body()));`.)